# как переносить строки в словаре?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке перехода строки с помощью (\n) в тексте просто выписывается \n
подскажите,в чем проблема?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не могли бы вы уточнить зачем в ключе `\n`. Какой результат вы хотите получить выполнив `print(dictionary)` ?

Comment: Что конкретно вы хотите получить? Текст с переносами строки при выводе значения на экран? Просто добавьте \n в нужных местах в текст. Если вам нужно чтобы текст значения разбивался на строки при выводе словаря на экран - этого вы не получите.

Comment: ну так  я и добавил \n в тексте , чтобы при выводе получить текст вертикальным отступом, но это не сработало

Comment: В тексте нет "\n", есть только "\".

Comment: я ее ставил как в ключе , так и в значении , так что она там есть

Answer (score 1):

```
dictionary = {"this is key\n":
                  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur dapibus mi id leo tempus, vitae aliquet enim iaculis. Phasellus."
              }

# правильный вывод ключей + значений из словаря
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Подробнее о работе со словарями, простым языком описано здесь: https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/slovari-dict-funkcii-i-metody-slovarej.html